# How do I export to iOS an Ionic project on Ubuntu?

Tags: ios, xcode, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionicv3 and I don't have MacOS so I cannot use Xcode.

Don't know if I could do something with Swift, and I'd like to know the best way to export to iOS app to test it on iPads or iPhones, is it possible?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you just need Xcode to generate the ipa or to run in real iphone, ipad devices. so you must install it anywhere.

Check this guide: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html As ionic is essentially cordova the steps are similar.

Recently i also tried these stuff, but i could't make it. Its better install macOS on VMware on your machine.And try out with xcode.

https://lazydevelo.com/blog/how-install-mac-os-x-high-sierra-vmware-linux/